# Excel with multiple Sheets causing issues with Open Xml

Tags: c#, plugins, dynamics-crm, openxml, openxml-sdk

I tried to create an excel with multiple sheets and different data count in both sheets. but when i tried to create only one row was getting added in both sheets and not more than that and when i open the excel it asks for repair.

`

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
                SpreadsheetDocument xl = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(ms, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);
                byte[] dt = null;
                // Add a WorkbookPart to the document
                WorkbookPart workbookPart = xl.AddWorkbookPart();
                workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();
                tracing.Trace("Temp Plugin Executed");
                Sheets sheets = xl.WorkbookPart.Workbook.AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

                // Begin: Code block for Excel sheet 1
                WorksheetPart worksheetPart1 = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                Worksheet workSheet1 = new Worksheet();
                SheetData sheetData1 = new SheetData();

                // the data for sheet 1
                Row rowInSheet1 = new Row();
                Cell emptyCell = CreateTextCell("A", "111", 1);
                rowInSheet1.Append(emptyCell);
                               sheetData1.Append(rowInSheet1);

                workSheet1.Append(sheetData1);
                worksheetPart1.Worksheet = workSheet1;

                Sheet sheet1 = new Sheet()
                {
                    Id = xl.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart1),
                    SheetId = 1,
                    Name = "Sheet1"
                };
                sheets.Append(sheet1);
                // End: Code block for Excel sheet 1

                // Begin: Code block for Excel sheet 2
                WorksheetPart worksheetPart2 = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>();
                Worksheet workSheet2 = new Worksheet();
                SheetData sheetData2 = new SheetData();

                // the data for sheet 2
                Row rowInSheet2 = new Row();
                Cell mycell = CreateTextCell("A", "data", 1);
                Cell mycell1 = CreateTextCell("A", "data", 2);
                rowInSheet2.Append(mycell);
                rowInSheet2.Append(mycell1);

                
                sheetData2.Append(rowInSheet2);

                workSheet2.Append(sheetData2);
                worksheetPart2.Worksheet = workSheet2;

                Sheet sheet2 = new Sheet()
                {
                    Id = xl.WorkbookPart.GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart2),
                    SheetId = 2,
                    Name = "Sheet2"
                };
                sheets.Append(sheet2);
                xl.Close();
                dt = ms.ToArray();
public Cell CreateTextCell(string header, string text, int index)
        {
            //Create a new inline string cell.
            Cell c = new Cell();
            c.DataType = CellValues.InlineString;
            c.CellReference = header + index;
            //Add text to the text cell.
            InlineString inlineString = new InlineString();
            Text t = new Text();
            t.Text = text;
            inlineString.AppendChild(t);
            c.AppendChild(inlineString);
            return c;
        }
```

`

I tried creating multiple sheets with different data count on both sheets

Comment: According to your code you are adding one row in Sheet1 with only one cell, and one row in Sheet2 with two cells.  So yes, you should see 2 sheets with a single row in each one of them.

Comment: ok can you let me know , how shall i add multiple items in both sheets and the count of records will be different in both sheets. where shalll i change in my code

Comment: @CristianRusanu as you are saying i am creating sheet 2 with two cells but the output is coming as sheet 2 with one cell only

Comment: Yes, I understand the problem. Posted the solution.

Answer (score 0):

The second cell should be B1 not A2. It's the second cell in the first row. That's how Excel works. So the code should look like:

```
Cell mycell = CreateTextCell("A", "data", 1);
Cell mycell1 = CreateTextCell("B", "data2", 1);
```

To add a second row on the second worksheet:

```
// the data for sheet 2
Row row2InSheet2 = new Row() { RowIndex = 2 };
sheetData2.Append(row2InSheet2);

// In the new row, find the column location to insert a cell in A2.  
Cell refCell = null;
foreach (Cell cell in row2InSheet2.Elements<Cell>())
{
    if (string.Compare(cell.CellReference.Value, "A2", true) > 0)
    {
        refCell = cell;
        break;
    }
}

Cell mycellRow21 = CreateTextCell("A", "new_row_test1", 2);
row2InSheet2.InsertBefore(mycellRow21, refCell);
```

You can study the Microsoft documentation on OpenXml for more [examples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/open-xml/working-with-sheets)

Comment: Thans, it worked, but how should i add the data in other rows,Row rowInSheet3 = new Row();
                
                Cell mycell2 = CreateTextCell("A", "data", 2);
                Cell mycell3 = CreateTextCell("B", "data", 2);
                rowInSheet3.Append(mycell2);
                rowInSheet3.Append(mycell3);